# (Frontend AJAX) get post data WITH image thumbnail?

Tags: ajax, post-thumbnails, get-post

I return data using the post id through AJAX. Now, what is the best way to "merge" the image thumbnail ( `get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'medium' )` ) into the data returned from the server?

I need this as a single JSON object for passing it to a template (all this is working fine, just need the image as well).

The simple idea:

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );

$post['image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'medium' );

echo json_encode( $post );
```

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by merge? can you please post your current code?

Comment: I'm simply trying to add the post image thumbnail to the post data output - to get all I need on the frontend in one single call to the server. Like: $post = get_post( $post_id );

$post['image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $the_post_id, 'medium' );

echo json_encode( $post );

Comment: I know. But if you want us to write an accurate answer, you need to provide us with the code you are currently using. Your idea works, but it seems you want something better. That's why i'm asking you to add your code so i can modify.

Comment: No, my »idea« does not work. I'd be more that thrilled if it did. I always try to make things as simple as possible, but somehow the inner »workings« of Wordpress seem to be giving me a hard time. In this case $post goes from being and Array to an Object when pushing parameters. I've also tried array_push ... no luck.

Comment: This is just one of the many things it throws at me: Fail:  Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), 9 more… }

Comment: OK THIS, was the missing parameter; ARRAY_A!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your idea doesn't work is, `get_post` returns a post object, not an array (if not set manually).

This is a quote from [WordPress code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/):

> When $output is OBJECT, a WP_Post instance is returned.

Which is the default output type for `get_post()`.
If you need to implement an array of data and then encode it using JSON, do this:

```
// Let's retrieve the post object
$post = get_post( $post_id );
// Set up the post data to use in our code
setup_postdata($post);
// Create an empty array for the data
$json_input = array();
$json_input['image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium' );
$json_input['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
$json_input['content'] = get_the_content();
$json_input['title'] = get_the_title();
// Now, we should reset the post data to avoid conflict
wp_reset_postdata();
// Our data is ready to be encoded, just, DO IT!
$json = json_encode($json_input);
```

However, you can set the output of `get_post()` to return an array, by changing the second argument:

```
get_post( $post_id, ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: Ok, found the solution and posted on top of your answer ... sorry.

Comment: @blaasvaer No problem, Glad it help you out.

Comment: @kaiser Well it was simply an answer to my own question. Why was is deleted?

Comment: @blaasvaer If the answer is duplicate, it will be removed by the moderator, because it already exists and is marked as accepted. You can read the guidelines [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/answering).

Comment: Yeah, I know. But if you look at the amount of text used to answer, and my extract, I bet another one needing the answer would get it quicker. And ideally with at link to the codex. Just saying.